# The Take-back counting algorithm

Tags: code-golf, sequence

Kids who are learning how to count often know runs of numbers, but can't seem to put those runs together properly.

For example, they might say:

```
1,2,3,4,7,8,9,10
```

Sometimes kids will realize that they skipped some numbers, and go back:

```
1,2,3,4,7,8,5,6,7,8,9,10
```

This is clearly the superior pattern.  We need to identify them.

To identify these lists:

1. We identify the minimum `M` and the maximum `N` of the list
2. We step through the list.  If the current number is greater than or equal to any member of the list to its right, then we remove the current number.
3. Iff the remaining list contains all numbers from `M` to `N`, then we return a truthy value.

You can assume your input list will contain at least 1 element.  You can assume that all integers will be non-negative.

### Test cases:

Truthy:

```
0
10
0 0 0 
1 0 1
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
0 1 2 3 0 1 2 3
0 1 2 3 4 5 5
0 1 1 2 2 3
0 3 6 1 4 7 2 5 8 3 4 5 6 7 8
1 3 5 7 2 3 4 5 6 7
5 6 0 1 2 3 6 7 4 5 6 7
5 6 7 8
5 5 6 7 8
4 6 7 8 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

Falsy:

```
1 0
4 3 2 1
1 2 3 7 8 9
0 1 2 3 1 3
0 1 2 3 1 3 4
0 1 2 3 1 3 2 4
0 1 2 3 1 3 2 4 3
1 3 5 7 2 4 6 8
0 1 2 1 3 4 5 6
4 5 6 3 4 5
```

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so make your answers as short as possible!

Comment: Not very clear: should [0,1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1] be considered true or false?

Comment: @GB False.  When you are on the second element, you would remove it on step 2 (because there's another `1` later down the line).  You'd also remove every other element (except for the last 1), so you'd end up with `0 1`, which is not `0 1 2 3 4 5`

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

I am not 100% certain this works, but it passes all test cases and I couldn't find any situation where it fails.

```
Ú¥1QP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3941qGlhoEB//9HG@oY6RjrmOiY61jomOqYgWlLHUODWAA)

```
Ú¥1QP   Main link. Argument a
Ú       Reverse uniquify a, keeps only last occurence of each element
 ¥      Get all deltas - all 1 if ascending list
  1Q    Compare all deltas to 1
    P   Product of all results
```

Comment: 7 bytes, in fact

Comment: @val No, 05AB1E uses a custom encoding, 05AB1E.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>10</s> 9 bytes

```
ṀrṂɓṚ«\Q⁼
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#ZU6xDcIwEOw9xY@Qj2MSJqCmoWIKJghpGIAOQUUJFUIREVRBFIxhL2LunYQYoThv3//d33nblCvbVO@tbXbtaTl364e396u9XVx1XuDHeW5Q1AuUoyv3bd3WrjyE5sz7RHGiEpJPMQoDMKWkKSNDE8qpoCkFTtfu7x@aCUhwN9EQMiY5sMGCaBlMNN55bKGkDvuEFfdFY77qrI8Ub5TcGGjIx/QcRRTL7Ael/xj8MZrYFD2DBzPVWQb0AQ)

#### How it works

```
ṀrṂɓṚ«\Q⁼  Main link. Argument: A (array)

Ṁ          Yield the maximum of A.
  Ṃ        Yield the minimum of A.
 r         Yield R := [max(A), ... min(A).
   ɓ       Begin a new chain. Left argument: A. Right argument: R
    Ṛ      Reverse A.
     «\    Take the cumulative minimum.
       Q   Unique; deduplicate the results.
        ⁼  Compare the result with R.
```

Comment: Interesting, is `ɓ` a relatively new feature?

Comment: Yes, it's from a pull request by Jonathan Allan.

Comment: Aha, 13 days ago. Hadn't seen it used yet though (maybe you or Jonathan have and I just missed it).

Comment: The real interesting part here is ``«\`` in my opinion though.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>59 54</s> 41 bytes

```ruby
->a{a.reverse|[]==[*a.max.downto(a.min)]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/ruby#pU9dC4JAEHzfX7HcQ2mgeKlpgf0RkzjIQCgVtQ/IfrvteWonPcbB3s3t7OzMOeqsvXgJu0rvaVWnbZxEUbwS9lU87VPxyJvCIJDlZvLumAPcAQflAU6FE@C4Rhc99HGDAYa4xZ6jvod7RvN7JLHquDTIqRMQ9klAE6MlLr0DfQXIOupJlv4vZ/xp2hssaYrMrstL1hjskDOTQpYvQGxFi@WtqfEci7GPqm0sdk1xzMwE3iApS8uylsAoPKm75IGDctJHn3JyLbPM4M3Q@hcT/5tV@g4HBh/dg8rQoz9SdB8)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 81 bytes

```python
x=input();r=m=[]
for n in x[::-1]:r=[n][:n<m]+r;m=r[0]
print r==range(m,max(x)+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#fVLRioMwEHzWr9g3laZgqp699PIfhZAHz9pDuKQltJC/95JNjnoqByLJzOzsZNn@dhmAQ5Zlk@Wjvj8feXEyXHEh0@vNgIZRgxWM7alkhgstBdMfSu7MSXEjSpnezagfYDg3nf4ackVUZ3Nb7GgxOdcUXc7eRQgnJyAo/ksC8UMMjzQS7nYgUBGoCTQE3gi0BI4E3h1VLjWv83Z184IDM5NWaE5R2iLTYKNl6xixQqxdp/N8OM77h@It1a9ns2xSz167CuEFOKmorLDRamh0YxQhfL0NH/5lotvi@SHo8U8ZnWeOGUP8CEspWZr4hbB@Ic7ukuDOuQ387tTnpWNgHTbYoYfebWaa4HZNPw)

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <strike>148</strike> 130 bytes

-18 bytes, thanks @Christoph

```php
$a=explode(' ',$argn);$b=range(min($a),max($a));foreach($a as$i=>&$k)for(;++$i<count($a);)$k<$a[$i]?:$k=-1;echo!array_diff($b,$a);
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#ZVBbT4MwFH7vrziSE4EMDR0gc4XtycQHE/euZukYDIIDAprMGH/7POUyIaZJ2@/0u6XBukorhpFs4ibUbMZtZgMtxmnndOcwBwdc8OAOfFjAPbSUbtyfE5rXIoW7F4eEnF58wh4ZjMwoxKG7P45gah/8FGs8Vxrvonb7SlNHm@YOqTnrPNrSl4Z81FaluxM0/4@J/9dSJS56Bh9yWZfeIk2wpKxjGaVGfKrey31saK@FZnUfbIJsAMtwhbI@FOY3i6O0hNkMy1vQl6CLM8pw0OmgWx1P4C6sZXGIjWNWGChN6yhP6jTFEIaSrDELV9eYmzQ0BLlmQVR@Fh@KKUzMA5QvmL2tl5iHN1yo7CtZ1/Jru8@SxMCdpYjnttPmcbN9eH4SP@df)

Comment: Ok a lot to comment here: `$argn` is always a string `foreach` doesn't work on it. You could use `$argv` to get an array as input but beware that it always contains the filename as first element. You use `$m` and `$n` only once so you can save a lot of bytes creating `$b` earlier: `$b=range(min($a),max($a));`. The cast `(bool)` is completly unnecessary. `if($k>=$a[$s])$a[$i]=null;` to `$k<$a[$s]?:$a[$i]=-1;`. Using reference we can do this: `foreach($a as$i=>&$k)` (+1 byte) and `$a[$i]` to `$k`(-4 byte). Moreover that lets us drop `$s=$i` because we can iterate over `$i`directly now.

Comment: The result looks like this `$a=$argn;$b=range(min($a),max($a));foreach($a as$i=>&$k)for(;++$i<count($a);)$k<$a[$i]?:$k=-1;echo!array_diff($b,$a);` (117 bytes). But it still uses `$argn` in the wrong way. `$a=explode(' ',$argn);` would fix this for 13 additional bytes.

Comment: @Christoph Thanks for the help, I'm rather new to golfing.

Comment: No problem ! Always nice to find a new PHP golfer I hope to see more of you :) either Titus, Jörg or me are always there to help !

Comment: @Christoph Why not using `$_GET` as Input array? In this case there is no need to use `explode` additonal -6 Bytes for using not the `$b` variable

Comment: @JörgHülsermann some nice ideas: `<?$b=$a=$_GET;foreach($a as$i=>&$k)for(;++$i<count($a);)$k<$a[$i]?:$k=-1;echo!array_diff(range(min($b),max($b)),$a);` 116 bytes. We still gotta copy `$_GET` twice because `$a` is modified.

Comment: @Christoph Would `<?$b=$a=$_GET;foreach($a as$i=>&$k)for(;~$c=$a[++$i];)$k<$c?:$k=-1;echo!array_d‌​iff(range(min($b),ma‌​x($b)),$a);` not work ?

Comment: @JörgHülsermann when testing on my server `$_GET` values are strings (and we need to give the numbers as e.g. `0=1&1=2&2=4`) and I get a fatal `Unsupported operand types`.

Comment: @Christoph Okay In this case we need a Version under 7.1 and we use ´a&` instead of `~` [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#Hcq9CsIwFIbh3avQ8FESGgd18zR2Em/ArZRyGhsTQn@Ii159rE4vPLxVvfhlg@52vZtGHIUWJ9FSRm/A5s/k5jSw9RK85ReCuRSIakVJXMCuX1OWCC0pxAq2PiOa/YEG6@cdp8Sf7hGck4mn5yDHMEn0So/8/lVpsKKcvw "PHP – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @Christoph any Idea to golfed this under 100? `<?foreach($g=$_GET as$v)($p=array_slice($g,++$k))&&$v>=min($p)?:$r[]=$v;echo$r==range($r[0],max($g));` M.E. you can get it [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/php#HYtBCsIwEADvvkLCUrq0B1FPxrUn8QPeQihLiE2pbcMWgr4@Bg9zmplrF0PcQf@4P8mos2rVsXBSVufXKp5dqGGgv9/zBglriMQi/O239@h8sW3TwIRYVZBuNI9LKbC7gBhLkLR3YQUhEl6GUos52HbmT/kQdc4/ "PHP – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @JörgHülsermann You should post the last one as your own answer because you have changed so much from my original version.

Comment: Take it as Gift. See it as our Teamwork. In the past there was always the case that for example Titus or Christoph helps me to improve my posts. Now I can help them sometimes or in this case you

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>264</s> 262 bytes

```
import java.util.*;l->{int m=Collections.max(l),n=Collections.min(l),i=0,q;for(;i<(q=l.size());i++)if(l.subList(i+1,q).size()>0&&l.get(i)>=Collections.min(l.subList(i+1,q)))l.remove(i--);for(i=0;n<=m;)if(i<l.size()&&l.get(i++)==n)n++;else return 0>1;return 1>0;}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#tZTBjtMwEIbvfYo5rWzqWvG2pSA3kRAnJNjLHhEHN7iVkeO0jlNYVn32Mk5TWNgLEoOSKIntfPP7n5m4Zt/GBF/M0cg@OS9f6Mmk9qbr4INx4XEC4EKycWtqC3f5FWDTtt6aADV7E6N5eO@6tH6Hi3Y2VuC5xkUnvPDskkmuhjsIUMLZz6pHhEFTvm29t3VybehkY74xz0X4fdCFPOjKQhz0to1MuzU7lF527rtlnGs3nXK3ZTjQb7IA5qZKHPg4XxU3N17uLA7z6jn4j4849zLapj1a5mYzPsTDyDqsy0bnKG59DfwTi@HLMvAwnWrrOwvRpj4GKCqlx0dVFfp0RjcB9v3Gow2jG8fWfYYGzWX3Kbqw@/gJDL84e//QJdvItk9yj1PJBxZkzYL9Cs@tvrjfSdMNeylwH4P3/4ZRRJxC4EEkCVGKSpUSt2IuFmIpXoqVeCVeC7odX9jjnV7wkg6ZoYQa52imQo0rhC7R1CcGU5XAHIGrp7mjAWfU1eOslxxOZsGS1tHFWP9/myqaPqbSPseEKarSyrkffgW0Lauo/wG5CRb0yNv/BKXa/q/eHyqVUqu6lj9VXeZOGpBX4GlyOv8A)

```
import java.util.*;                 // Import for Collections

l->{                                // Method with integer-ArrayList parameter and boolean return-type
  int m=Collections.max(l),         //  Max of the list
      n=Collections.min(l),         //  Min of the list
      i=0,q;                        //  Two temp integers
  for(;i<(q=l.size());i++)          //  Loop (1) over the list
    if(l.subList(i+1,q).size()>0    //   If the sublist right of the current item is not empty
    &&l.get(i)>=Collections.min(l.subList(i+1,q))) 
                                    //   and if the current item is larger or equal to the lowest value of this sublist
      l.remove(i--);                //    Remove the current item from the main list
                                    //  End of loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
  for(i=0;n<=m;)                    //  Loop (2) from min to max
    if(i<l.size()                   //   If the current item doesn't exceed the list's size
    &&l.get(i++)==n)                //   and the items are in order so far
      n++;                          //    Go to the next item
    else                            //   Else:
      return 0>1;//false            //    Return false
                                    //  End of loop (2) (implicit / single-line body)
  return 1>0;//true                 //  Return true
}                                   // End of method
```

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>88</s> 85 bytes

```
y=NULL;for(i in x<-scan())if(all(i<x[-(1:(F<-F+1))]))y=c(y,i);all(min(x):max(x)%in%y)
```

This can probably be golfed down further. Loops over the elements of `x`, checks if all upcoming values are bigger, and only then keeps that element. After the loop it creates a sequence from `min(x)` to `max(x)`, and checks with `%in%` if all values are included in the pruned version of `x`.

Comment: By porting Dennis' answer we could get down to 53 bytes. `function(n)all(unique(cummin(rev(n)))==max(n):min(n))`

Answer (score 1):

### JavaScript (ES6), 60 bytes

```
s=>(o={},s.reverse().every((n,i)=>!i|o[n+1]|o[n]&&(o[n]=1)))
```

**Ungolfed:**

```
s=>(
  o={},
  s.reverse().every((n,i)=>
    !i|o[n+1]|o[n]&&(o[n]=1)
  )
)
```

This is a simpler algorithm:

Iterate the array in reverse, and make sure each number (except the first) is one less than or equal to a number already seen.

**Snippet:**

```js
f=

s=>(o={},s.reverse().every((n,i)=>!i|o[n+1]|o[n]&&(o[n]=1)))

console.log('Truthy');
console.log(f([0]))
console.log(f([10]))
console.log(f([0,0,0]))
console.log(f([1,0,1]))
console.log(f([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]))
console.log(f([0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3]))
console.log(f([0,1,2,3,4,5,5]))
console.log(f([0,1,1,2,2,3]))
console.log(f([0,3,6,1,4,7,2,5,8,3,4,5,6,7,8]))
console.log(f([1,3,5,7,2,3,4,5,6,7]))
console.log(f([5,6,0,1,2,3,6,7,4,5,6,7]))
console.log(f([5,6,7,8]))
console.log(f([5,5,6,7,8]))
console.log(f([4,6,7,8,3,4,5,6,7,8]))

console.log('Falsy');
console.log(f([1,0]))
console.log(f([4,3,2,1]))
console.log(f([1,2,3,7,8,9]))
console.log(f([0,1,2,3,1,3]))
console.log(f([0,1,2,3,1,3,4]))
console.log(f([0,1,2,3,1,3,2,4]))
console.log(f([0,1,2,3,1,3,2,4,3]))
console.log(f([1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8]))
console.log(f([0,1,2,1,3,4,5,6]))
console.log(f([4,5,6,3,4,5]))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 62 bytes

```
g(a:b)=[a|all(a<)b]++g b
g a=a
f x=g x==[minimum x..maximum x]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#bY7PDoIwDMbvPEUPHiA2hPFH0LgnWXYoMRASh8RowsF3x1JQF0OWrfvar@1vakM61ZE29KLrNaRzVNv9voU6aIE0BQ2MuuWrjev6zj0djHHsaFy@dnLU9aDhcgsAhnvXP2AHjgZowJjEolHzkyCfWXBUohWmmGGOBR6wxAqPuBqXwholk7FFsbXkTMFWr01GZqxKfxxnf/XC8@brMn@C3eBWApuzLxXchUkwPUa18n0V5n863cpI1496Zqq@LvVhk/0zo2hrpzc)

A direct implementation of the definition where `g` removes the elements if they are >= than the the elements to its right.

Answer (score 1):

## C#, 69 bytes

```cs
s=>s.Where((e,i)=>s.Skip(i+1).All(r=>e<r)).Count()==s.Max()-s.Min()+1
```

In short:
s = input (s)equence
take from s element where all items after this one (skip (I)ndex + 1 items), current value is higher
count these, and see if the amount left is equal to the amount expected ((max)imum value minus (min)imum) amount of numbers

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVRNT@MwEL3nV4x6wRathfuxhS2pVCGhPYCESBFCFQcT3NbCm3Rth6VC/e3dcWlFaJ2WwzqHyDPPb57njZzaRmrTZWFVNoFkbp383YvKO3alsj@9aFY8aZVCqoW18AbvkXXCYeA1V89wLVRGKAbhssjSc5W50WMdnvJc92EM8dLGfcvup9JIQmRdUb9NXtSMqGNO2UBrYuK@PDeUsou8yByhcWzZtXgjtIF/T37Ml70ogtJ6FQacKdx0DjFk8u/o0QvYWrWTWn03yIPRE8AvCMcED5/g0IQWtKEDP6ALp3AGVdwfyPX/EFmnCuAhledbKILj@S5COiimJCx8rRamu@UbhGA@sdHmuQ5AK4p19ilpr7tXFvwFtWCJ1DJ1RELcB8mSmVaOHMER3SQmPoGDx26EsZJMcJSG@cAYMSeU9nYGZyy03Ts3PDwKbdTYDA/DR4dWQ7DPXr7ffW9K@xCg@S1IuNCn677rp9U8fGNHuA/epxXgPzv1he0iz2yuJbs3ykl8iCSpDW/vhr8efta2TB3nRop0CmT1LCD/@m3AVynAMiYOa8Ei2k1t8QYUXA6uku8IWM3YgfqLxfIf)

Comment: @MDXF Do you want to welcome him?

Comment: @StanStrum did i misunderstand the rules? is my english too messy? i -am- posting for the first time...

Comment: No, no! It's a privilege to welcome a newcomer to PPCG, and I was asking him if he'd wanted to say hi to you

Comment: Looks like the privilege is to the both of you. Thanks, people ^^

Comment: This is a great first answer, hope you have fun in your future of PPCG!

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>82</s> <s>73</s> <s>72</s> 70 bytes

Returns a boolean.

```js
a=>a.filter((x,i)=>k-=a.every(y=>~i--<0|y>x,m=x>m?x:m),m=k=0)[0]+~m==k
```

#### How?

We iterate on each element ***x*** of the input array ***a***, keeping track of the maximum encountered value ***m*** and the number ***-k*** of values that are not greater than or equal to any member to their right. By definition, valid values appear in strictly ascending order.

We use `filter()` rather than `map()`, so that all elements get filtered out until ***k*** turns negative. This allows us to isolate the first valid element, which is also guaranteed to be the minimum value of the array.

Finally, we test whether `minimum - (maximum + 1) == -number_of_valid_elements`:

```
a.filter(...)[0] + ~m == k
```

#### Test cases

```js
let f =

a=>a.filter((x,i)=>k-=a.every(y=>~i--<0|y>x,m=x>m?x:m),m=k=0)[0]+~m==k

console.log('[Truthy]');
console.log(f([0]));
console.log(f([10]));
console.log(f([0,0,0,]));
console.log(f([1,0,1]));
console.log(f([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]));
console.log(f([0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3]));
console.log(f([0,1,2,3,4,5,5]));
console.log(f([0,1,1,2,2,3]));
console.log(f([0,3,6,1,4,7,2,5,8,3,4,5,6,7,8]));
console.log(f([1,3,5,7,2,3,4,5,6,7]));
console.log(f([5,6,0,1,2,3,6,7,4,5,6,7]));
console.log(f([5,6,7,8]));
console.log(f([5,5,6,7,8]));
console.log(f([4,6,7,8,3,4,5,6,7,8]));

console.log('[Falsy]');
console.log(f([1,0]));
console.log(f([4,3,2,1]));
console.log(f([1,2,3,7,8,9]));
console.log(f([0,1,2,3,1,3]));
console.log(f([0,1,2,3,1,3,4]));
console.log(f([0,1,2,3,1,3,2,4]));
console.log(f([0,1,2,3,1,3,2,4,3]));
console.log(f([1,3,5,7,2,4,6,8]));
console.log(f([0,1,2,1,3,4,5,6]));
console.log(f([4,5,6,3,4,5]));
```